# JsonEditor component in vue is not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having trouble showing my JsonEditor component. This is the code that i am working with:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
  <div class="admin">

    <v-alert v-if="info.showAlert"
      value=true
      :type="info.alertType">
    {{info.message}}
    </v-alert>

    <h2>Welcome to scope360 admins area. A place to edit scope360 configurations</h2>
    <v-btn class="test" @click="switchEditClicked">{{switchButtonMessage}}</v-btn>
    <div class= "editorComponents">
      <div v-if="showJsonEditor" class="editor">
        <json-editor is-edit="true" v-model="editedConfig" ></json-editor>
        <v-btn @click="previewClicked">Preview Changes</v-btn>
      </div>
      <div v-if="!showJsonEditor" class="jsonDiff">
        <vue-json-compare :oldData="originalConfig" :newData="editedConfig"></vue-json-compare>
        <v-btn @click="saveClicked">Save</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="cancelPreviewClicked">Cancel</v-btn>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>

import JsonEditor from 'vue-edit-json'
import vueJsonCompare from 'vue-json-compare'

import{getConfig,updateConfig} from "../utils/network";


export default{

  components: {
   'vue-json-compare' : vueJsonCompare,
   'json-editor' : JsonEditor
 },

  data: function () {
    return {
      originalConfig: {},
      editedConfig: {},
      showJsonEditor: true,
      switchButtonMessage: "plain text",
      info : {
        showAlert: false,
        alertType: "success",
        message: ""
      },
   }
  },
```

What am i missing? There is no errors when running. I am retrieving information from my backend to display some JSON information.

*The component has worked before, after som changes in design it stopped working
*Yes, i have checked if the data i am retrieving to display is correct and exists

**Update**

I made it work again but i would still love to know why my first attempt is not working?

This works:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(JsonEditor)

  components: {
   'vue-json-compare' : vueJsonCompare

 },

//HTML
  <JsonEditor is-edit="true" v-model="editedConfig" ></JsonEditor>
```

**Update 2, Link to JsonEditor**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-edit-json

Comment: Hi, is it `vue-json-compare` not working properly?

Comment: Hi, no it is JsonEditor @JeremyWalters

Comment: Hard to say. Can you link the lib you using(JsonEditor). Which could also help if you can get it working on jsfiddle.

Comment: @JeremyWalters link is up

Comment: I am seeing that the creator of the module also describes in the "usage" section that it should be done with `Vue.use`could it be related on how the person built the module?

Comment: I see the author doesn't export the component, so it would appear that the only way to use it is by `Vue.use`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question on why it's not importing the component with your first approach. That's because the author decided to make it a [plugin](https://github.com/fingerpich/vue-edit-json/blob/master/src/index.js) instead of importable component. (See Vue docs on [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin)).

Such that when you do `import` on this component, it may be imported but never rendered since it's written without exporting the `default` module.

If you need to register this component by the `import` keyword, you could specify the complete path to the component file itself.

```
import JsonEditor from "vue-edit-json/src/JsonEditor";

new Vue({

  components: {
    JsonEditor
  }
    
}
```

And that should give you the same effect.

---

BTW, a quick [tip](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#With-PascalCase) for you:

> When defining a component with PascalCase, you can use either case when referencing its custom element. That means both `<my-component-name>` and `<MyComponentName>` are acceptable.

So in your case, since you seem to want to have the components in kebab-case, you could drop the component "alias" name from the `components` object.

```
import VueJsonCompare from 'vue-json-compare';

components: {
  VueJsonCompare
}

// ...

<vue-json-compare :oldData="originalConfig" :newData="editedConfig"></vue-json-compare>
```